# How to get user profile while signing in with Google account?

Tags: google-oauth

I have a website, how can I get user profile while a website visitor visits my website and click the button "Sign in with Google account"?

According to the page of https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid, I added a callback function as:

```
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="MY_CLIENT_ID"
     data-context="signin"
     data-ux_mode="popup"
     data-callback="handleGoogleSignIn"
     data-login_uri="https://MY_LOGIN_PAGE"
     data-auto_prompt="false">
</div>
```

My callback function is:

```
function handleGoogleSignIn(response)
{
    alert(response.credential)
}
```

I found there are four keys in response: cliendId, client_id, crential, and select_by.

[image]

I also found this page https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in. But it is a deprecated page.

My questions is how to get user profile (such as user name, email...) while signing in with user's Google account? Thanks.